# Cordova watchPosition does not restart the GPS request on phone

Tags: android, cordova, gps, geolocation

I'm working with Cordovas Geolocation Plugin.

When the Phone is ready watchPosition does start. If GPS is activated BEFORE starting the app, everything works fine.
But if I start GPS afterwards, watchPosition does not start the GPS request on my phone, so watchPosition just shows the error message frequently.

Do you have any idea, how to restart watchPosition with GPS request?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I've found that clearing the existing watcher then re-adding a new one resolves this issue on Android; something like this:

```
var MAX_POSITION_ERRORS_BEFORE_RESET = 3,
positionWatchId = null, 
watchpositionErrorCount = 0;

function addWatch(){
    positionWatchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onWatchPositionSuccess, onWatchPositionError, options);
}

function clearWatch(){
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(positionWatchId);
}


function onWatchPositionError(err) {
    watchpositionErrorCount++;
    if (watchpositionErrorCount >= MAX_POSITION_ERRORS_BEFORE_RESET) {        
        clearWatch();
        addWatch();
        watchpositionErrorCount = 0;
    }

}
addWatch();
```

Comment: THX, DUDE! You made my day :)

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. Please could you mark this as the accepted answer for the benefit of others